# How to build and Interface a Fortran95 library with C

Tags: compilation, linker, fortran, static-libraries

I'm porting an old C++ project to run on RHEL 6.7 with gcc 4.4.7.  The code was originally made to run on an SGI machine.

I have a library `.a` which is presumed to have been compiled on the old machine (and thus there's no hope of running it in the new one) however, along with this `.a` file I also have the headers and source files.  I am assuming that these are the ones that are used to make the `.a` file.  The Makefile that was used is now long gone, I just have the source code.

My question is, is there a way to "reverse engineer" the library?  I would like to know what functions the `.a` library contains so I can make it on my machine.

I will add that I am new to static and shared libraries so I'm not entirely sure what the `.a` file contains or how it is any different from including the headers.

Update:

I have looked into the included code and realized that the C files only work to interface with functions defined using Fortran95.  I think that now I'm supposed to build the Fortran95 codebase and somehow interface that with the C code.  Once I do that I will have a library that should (hopefully) compile in my native system.  How can I do this?

Comment: If you have the source code, why do you have to reverse engineering it?

Comment: Since it is just a library, why not compile the whole thing?  Whatever functions are unused, well, they just go unused.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I know that from the source code there are at least 2 `.a` files that are generated out of it.

Comment: You're not trying to reverse engineer it so much as figure out how to compile it, or *re-engineer* it for modern compiler environments. You'll probably have to change a ton of code if this was using the SGI "Standard Template Library" from aeons ago, that doesn't exist any more, and porting to the Standard Library might be a ton of work.

Comment: How do you normally compile source files into a static library? What are you unable to do to recreate that here?

Comment: @Galik From the source code it seems that more than one `.a` file can be generated.  So I would ideally have liked to see what each individual `.a` contained

Comment: If you link the program that needs the library without including the library shouldn't the linker errors tell you what functions are needed?

Comment: So after looking at the source files in more detail I realized that the source files that are written in C are themselves wrappers to some functions defined in Fortran. I will update the question to make it more clear, @tadman was right, its not reverge engineers is re-engineering this rather confusion codebase

Comment: Sounds like you've got a project and a half there. You may need to re-implement everything from the ground up, piece by piece, systematically. While there are modern Fortran compilers, unless you really understand Fortran that may be of zero help. If you have an old SGI machine that can run the binaries as-is you at least have a reference implementation to compare your new one to for testing.

Comment: @tadman And this is just one of the many libraries I need to get working!